# Rails Server Launch Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need help to fix my ruby. It was working perfectly fine until this morning when I tried to start up my rails server and I've received this error msg:

> Daniels-MacBook-Pro:myrubyblog daniellim$ rails s -p 5040 /Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in load': cannot load such file -- /Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)     from /Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in main>'

I have tried bundle install and update but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails s` work any better? Maybe your system `rails` gem is broken.

Comment: It does start up but then loading into an error page.

Comment: which versions of ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: @Nirupa the version is ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: and rails version?

Comment: When I check rails This is what came out  >>>                                   Daniels-MacBook-Pro:myrubyblog daniellim$ rails -v
/Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
 from /Users/daniellim/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error you are getting which is you don't have the rails (or right version of rails) installed.

Therefore, first install rails on your system

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

Or if you already have it installed, update it

```
gem update rails
```

Tell me if I am missing on something?

Comment: Hey buddy, I have done the update. but my localhost page shows error >>Showing /Users/daniellim/ruby/myrubyblog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Permission denied @ utime_internal - /Users/daniellim/ruby/myrubyblog/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/DS/DSOLSc6A5RVSmvM415eEWAWG_AgOvZcLZOXQjsXyWQA.cache
Extracted source (around line #5):

Comment: I have updated my answer, try updating rails using above link.

Comment: did u try to install first? if that doesn't work then try to update

Comment: I am doing it again.. hopefully it works. I have also updated the rails version to the latest version 5.0.0 beta

Comment: I hope so too.. Let me know how it goes

Comment: After updating ruby and I went check rails -v error msg shows again

Comment: Now I am calling sudo gem install rails hopefully it will solve the problem

Comment: I am still having this error on my localhost page >>Permission denied @ utime_internal - /Users/daniellim/ruby/myrubyblog/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/DS/DSOLSc6A5RVSmvM415eEWAWG_AgOvZcLZOXQjsXyWQA.cache

Comment: Hi @Nirupa, yes. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem.. Good luck ahead !